How to use reverse engineering to replicate websocket request
how I can use reverse engineering technique to get known how websocket is working on website. What data my browser is sending to websocket so it reply with data. How I can replicate that process as curl / in code so I can receive same data as the one in my browser developer tools that is in 'messages' section.
